# Extract text from an aria-label selenium webdriver (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Right now I'm working on a program that takes user input of questions and answers, separates them into separate lists of q's and a's, then automatically answers the question given either the question or answer. Since the place where the 'bot' is being used is online, I'm using the Selenium web driver, which is causing me some problems when trying to read an aria-label. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as I'm not advanced at all with selenium, HTML, or CSS. I'm trying to find the aria-label value for each container without knowing what it is

**An example of the HTML I'm trying to get the text value of:**

```
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard-tile"><div class="MatchModeQuestionGridTile" touch-action="auto"><div class="MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content"><div aria-label="to cloak; to conceal the truth; to offer lame excuses" class="FormattedText notranslate TermText MatchModeQuestionGridTile-text lang-en" style="font-size: 14px;"><div style="display: block;">to cloak; to conceal the truth; to offer lame excuses</div></div></div></div></div>
```

**Snippet of my code:**

```
def driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(link)
    startMatch = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button").click()
   
    #find text in matches
    container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content')
    containerFile = open("QuizletTerms.txt", "w+")

    for _ in list(container):
        arialabel = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='']")
        containerFile.write("\n")
        containerFile.write(str(arialabel))
        print(arialabel)

    containerFile.close()
    print("done")
    sleep(5)
```

### Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texts e.g. **to cloak; to conceal the truth; to offer lame excuses** is present in child `<div>` as well in it's parent `<div>`. So extract it you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("aria-label") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content>div[aria-label]")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("aria-label") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content']/div[@aria-label]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```