# Extract all the src attribute from the images of Amazon Product Page in Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium to scrape details from an Amazon product page ([Example][1]). I've successfully scraped the product title, but I also want to get the URLs of all of the product images. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def search_amazon():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/Pendleton-Glacier-National-Queen-Blanket/dp/B003EQ4AYY/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dZURJ&pf_rd_p=ab102187-3a5a-49fd-b43f-4f928775aeae&pf_rd_r=PD8YGV8XA34FMYH7G9TJ&pd_rd_r=2cb55e9c-812a-43de-bf52-7e1976f5374b&pd_rd_wg=KmkoW&ref_=pd_gw_hfp13n_bbn')
    productName = driver.find_element_by_id('productTitle').text
    print(productName)
    imgList = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="altImages"]/ul')
    options = imgList.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

    for option in options:
        print(option.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

search_amazon()
```

The options loop at the end returns the innerHTML of each LI. I'm unable to access the IMG src though, what I've attempted is:

```
for option in options:
    src = option.find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute("src")
```

This throws a NoSuchElementException:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"img"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *src* attributes of the `<img>` tags you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/Pendleton-Glacier-National-Queen-Blanket/dp/B003EQ4AYY/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dZURJ&pf_rd_p=ab102187-3a5a-49fd-b43f-4f928775aeae&pf_rd_r=PD8YGV8XA34FMYH7G9TJ&pd_rd_r=2cb55e9c-812a-43de-bf52-7e1976f5374b&pd_rd_wg=KmkoW&ref_=pd_gw_hfp13n_bbn')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#altImages>ul li[data-ux-click] img")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/Pendleton-Glacier-National-Queen-Blanket/dp/B003EQ4AYY/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dZURJ&pf_rd_p=ab102187-3a5a-49fd-b43f-4f928775aeae&pf_rd_r=PD8YGV8XA34FMYH7G9TJ&pd_rd_r=2cb55e9c-812a-43de-bf52-7e1976f5374b&pd_rd_wg=KmkoW&ref_=pd_gw_hfp13n_bbn')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='altImages']/ul//li[@data-ux-click]//img")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Sj%2BO--J9L._AC_US40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41iX14X%2BoRL._AC_US40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41wiU-3N5JL._AC_US40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41waNtDjTxL._AC_US40_.jpg']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Getting specific elements in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068370/getting-specific-elements-in-selenium/64071682#64071682)
- [Cannot find table element from div element in selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868291/cannot-find-table-element-from-div-element-in-selenium-python/59868504#59868504)
- [Extract text from an aria-label selenium webdriver (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946115/extract-text-from-an-aria-label-selenium-webdriver-python/63946412#63946412)

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual image not the thumbs, i did it using hover function. Adding Waits would be safe to add.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
...

for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#altImages .imageThumbnail'):
      hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i)
      hover.perform()
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.image.item.maintain-height.selected img').get_attribute('src'))
```

This would get the actual fullsize image srcs

Answer (score 0):

When you are finding `li` elements for every image you should specify the class of the element in your path because not every `li` of the element `//*[@id="altImages"]/ul` refer to an image. So in order to find the urls you can do like this:

```
def search_amazon():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/Pendleton-Glacier-National-Queen-Blanket/dp/B003EQ4AYY/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dZURJ&pf_rd_p=ab102187-3a5a-49fd-b43f-4f928775aeae&pf_rd_r=PD8YGV8XA34FMYH7G9TJ&pd_rd_r=2cb55e9c-812a-43de-bf52-7e1976f5374b&pd_rd_wg=KmkoW&ref_=pd_gw_hfp13n_bbn')
    productName = driver.find_element_by_id('productTitle').text
    print(productName)
    imgList = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="altImages"]/ul')
    options = imgList.find_elements_by_xpath(".//li[contains(@class, 'imageThumbnail')]")

    for option in options:
        print(option.find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scrape complete image from amazon product**

```
i=1
while i<15:
    try:
        btn=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'*//ul/li['+str(i)+']/span/span/span/input').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        main=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.image.item.maintain-height.selected img').get_attribute('src')
        image_url.append(main)
        print(main)
    except:
        pass
    i=i+1
```